# pgfplots: How to get a legend of fill area?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, legend, fillbetween

I want to make a bar plot and put the average with error bar or an error behind it. So far I got it working, except I can't get the filled area to show up in the legend. Here is my working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units,
fillbetween} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymajorgrids,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Si pro Zelle},
ymin=0,
ytick={0,2,...,16},
symbolic x coords={0, 5 Tage, 6 Tage, 7 Tage, 8 Tage, 1}, 
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,  
    anchor=east}, 
]
\addplot[ybar, ybar legend,blue, fill=blue!30!white, 
    error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,
    ]
    table[x=x,y=y,y error=error,col sep=comma] {test.csv};
\addlegendentry{Si-Pool}
\addplot [red,line legend,
    sharp plot,update limits=false,
    ] coordinates { (0,7.524) (1,7.524) }
    node [above] at (6 Tage,7.524) {Average};
\addlegendentry{Average}    
\addplot [transparent,name path=B,sharp plot, update limits=false,
    ] coordinates {(0,5.474)   (1,5.474) };
\addplot [transparent,name path=A,sharp plot,update limits=false,
    ] coordinates { (0,9.574) (1,9.574) };
\addplot [red!10!white,area legend] fill between [
    of=A and B];
\addlegendentry{Error}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
test
\end{document}
```

I have tried the package manual and google but didn't find something. Does anyone have an idea how to get the fill area/color to show up in the legend?

Thanks in advance!

I have two more minor issues:

1. Is there a more elegant way to let the average line start at the axis, not outside the plot?
2. How can I change only the color of the error bars?

`\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv} 
    x   y   error
    5 Tage  4.031   0.457
    6 Tage  6.205   0.065
    7 Tage  14.275  0.869
    8 Tage  5.585   0.229
\end{filecontents*}`

[image: Plot]

Comment: Please add filecontents and the settings that you use to your code to make it a real MWE.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294660/fill-square-mark-in-legend

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295102/how-to-choose-options-for-example-the-color-globally-for-every-fill-between-plot

Comment: Does my answer answer your questions or do you need further assistance? In the first case please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) and [accepting](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). In the later case, please edit your question accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You only made one small mistake to achieve what you want: `\addlegendentry` is not adding a legend entry to the previous `\addplot` command, but just collects entries. So only the *order* of these commands is of interest to produce the legend, not the *place* where you write the command(s). Said that, the picture of the "Error" entry in the legend actually shows the style of the "`name path=B`" `\addplot` which you defined as `transparent`.

To prove the said just add two more `\addlegendentry` commands and the "last one" will show (correctly) the style of the "`fill between`" `\addplot` command.

But this is not a real solution, because also if you just state empty arguments to the `\addlegendentry` command, these will occupy space in the legend. To prevent this, you can either use the `\legend` command instead (which I did in the shown solution below) or you can use `legend entries` in the `axis` options, where empty entries will not be added to the legend.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    x,       y,       error
    5 Tage,  4.031,   0.457
    6 Tage,  6.205,   0.065
    7 Tage,  14.275,  0.869
    8 Tage,  5.585,   0.229
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymajorgrids,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
        },
        ylabel={Si pro Zelle},
        ymin=0,
        ytick distance=2,           % <-- replaced `ytick' key
        symbolic x coords={
            0, 5 Tage, 6 Tage, 7 Tage, 8 Tage, 1},
        xtick=data,
        x tick label style={
            rotate=45,
            anchor=east,
        },
        axis on top,                % <-- added
    ]

        \addplot [
            ybar,
            ybar legend,
            blue,
            fill=blue!30!white,
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit,
        ] table [
            x=x,
            y=y,
            y error=error,
            col sep=comma,
        ] {test.csv};

        \addplot [
            red,
            line legend,
            update limits=false,
        ] coordinates {
            (0,7.524)
            (1,7.524)
        }
            % specified relative positioning, rather than an absolute one
            node [above,pos=0.5] {Average}
        ;

        \addplot [
            transparent,
            name path=B,
            update limits=false,
        ] coordinates {
            (0,5.474)
            (1,5.474)
        };

        \addplot [
            transparent,
            name path=A,
            update limits=false,
        ] coordinates {
            (0,9.574)
            (1,9.574) }
        ;

        \addplot [
            red!10!white,
            area legend,
        ] fill between [
            of=A and B,
        ];

        \legend{
            Si-Pool,
            Average,
            ,
            ,
            Error,
        }

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]